# Как воспользоваться self.kwargs вне CBV ? (Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Приступил к изучению Джанго и вот нарвался на такую проблему. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как то использовать конструкцию `self.kwargs[]` вне Class Based View?

Объясню:
Есть представление:

```
Сlass NewsByCategory(ListView): 
    model = News
    template_name = 'news/home_news_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'news'
    allow_empty = False

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)  # контекст модели
        context['title'] = Category.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['category_id'])  
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return News.objects.filter(category_id=self.kwargs['category_id'], is_published=True)
```

Есть путь из url.py:

```
path('category/<int:category_id>/', NewsByCategory.as_view(extra_context={'title': 'Какой-то тайтл'}),
         name='category'),
```

И есть кастомный тэг:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('news/list_categories.html')
def show_categories(arg1='Hello', arg2='World'):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return {'categories': categories, 'arg1': arg1, 'arg2': arg2}
```

Данный кастомный тэг рендерит шаблон:

```
<div class="list-group">
    {%for item in categories%}
    <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{item.title}}</a>
    {% endif %}
    {%endfor%}
</div>
```

Зачем мне это надо: Сейчас при помощи данного тэга создаётся боковая панелька в которой выводятся ссылки на новости с конкретной категорией. Так вот я бы хотел, чтобы на странице с новостями определённой категории, ссылка на эту же страницу была не активна. т.е. если к примеру открыта страница с новостями о спорте, то хотелось бы, чтобы в боковой панели были активны ссылки на все остальные страницы, кроме текущей.

вот как я примерно вижу шаблон боковой панели:

```
<div class="list-group">
    {%for item in categories%}
    {% if item.pk !=  self.kwargs['category_id'] %}
    <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{item.title}}</a>
    {% elif %}
    <p class="selected">{{item.title}}</p>
    {% endif %}
    {%endfor%}
</div>
```

Осталось понять как реализовать это в кастомном тэге...

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Ты же уже передаешь некие аргументы arg1 и arg2 в шаблонный тег. так передай текущий id категории туда. а текущую категорию ты и так уже добавляешь в контекст шаблона

```
@register.inclusion_tag('news/list_categories.html')
def show_categories(arg1='Hello', arg2='World', cur_category=None):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return {'categories': categories, 'arg1': arg1, 'arg2': arg2, 'cur_category': cur_category}
```

```
<div class="list-group">
    {%for item in categories%}
        {% if item.pk !=  cur_category  %}
            <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{item.title}}</a>
        {% elif %}
            <p class="selected">{{item.title}}</p>
        {% endif %}
    {%endfor%}
</div>
```

ну вот как пример. имеем набор магазинов (далее shop) и набор продуктов (products). Каждый продукт привязан к магазину.

```
{% for item in shops %}
    {% if item.pk == shop_id %}
        <span> {{ item }} </span>
    {% else %}
        <a href="/newapp/{{ item.pk }}/">{{ item }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

код тега

```
@register.inclusion_tag('newapp/inctag.html')
def show_shops(shop_id=None):
    shops = models.Shop.objects.all()
    return {"shop_id": shop_id, "shops": shops}
```

и код страницы где этот тег используется

```
{% load shop_extras %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% show_shops title.pk %}
</body>
</html>
```

А код вьюхи я у тебя взял. Только модели свои поставил

```
class NewsByCategory(ListView):
    model = models.Product
    template_name = 'newapp/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'news'
    allow_empty = False

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)  # контекст модели
        context['title'] = models.Shop.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['shop_id'])
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Product.objects.filter(shop__id=self.kwargs['shop_id'])
```